# SQL Query that will omit records with the same ID based on values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

*** UPDATE***

Upon further review, the table I am using also has a `linenumber` column.  See updated example data below.  I feel like this could be extremely helpful in solving this....just not sure how.  Sum up the line number by PO, and if it equals 1 it is a single line, if it is greater than 1 it is a multi line....does that do anything for us?

New here and to SQL so please forgive my ignorance.  Hopefully this is an easy answer.

Looking to build 3 similar queries that will return purchase orders that contain more than 1 item and:

1. Contain NO Lot Controlled Items
2. Contain ALL Lot Controlled Items
3. Contain a MIX of Lot Controlled and Non-Lot Controlled Items

Data looks like this...

```
PONUMBER    ITEMNUMBER  LOTCONTROLLED  LINENUMBER
PO1.18      OSC1024     0              1
PO1.18      OSC1025     0              2
PO1.18      OSC1026     0              3
PO1.2       OSC1199     0              1
PO1.2       OSC1200     1              2
PO1.21      OSC1201     1              1
PO1.21      OSC1202     1              2
PO1.22      OSC1203     1              1
PO1.23      OSC1204     1              1
PO1.23      OSC1205     0              2
PO1.24      OSC1206     1              1
PO1.24      OSC1207     1              2
PO1.24      OSC1300     0              3
```

Query for NO Lot Controlled items works great...

```
    SELECT 
      `POD`.`PONUMBER`,
      `POD`.`ITEMNUMBER`,
      `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
    FROM
      table1 AS `POD`
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT `PONUMBER`, COUNT(`PONUMBER`)
        FROM table1
        WHERE `LOTCONTROLLED` = 0
        GROUP BY `PONUMBER`
        HAVING (COUNT(`PONUMBER`) > 1)
       ) as `POD1`
     ON `POD`.`PONUMBER` = `POD1`.`PONUMBER`
```

I thought it would be as simple as changing the `WHERE LOTCONTROLLED` to be = 1, to get Purchase Orders with ALL Lot Controlled items, but that returns some Purchase Orders that have mixed lines as well.

How can I eliminate a purchase order from inclusion if any one of the lines are not lot controlled?

Comment: I think your No Lot Controlled query suffers the same mistake ALL would, just that the data is more convenient. Try replacing `LOTCONTROLLED` for a `PO1.18` to `1` and see that if it still works.

Comment: You are correct.  And upon further review it appears my queries to isolate single line purchase orders with and without LOT controlled items is also "suffering".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are the simplest method, but you probably don't have those.  So, just use the `min()` and `max()` of `lotcontrolled`.  The basic query is:

```
select pod.* 
from table1 pod join
      (select ponumber, min(lotcontrolled) as min_lc, max(lotcontrolled) as max_lc
       from table1 pod
       group by ponumber
       having count(*) > 1
      ) p
      using (ponumber)
```

Then your three conditions are:

```
max_lc = 0  -- no lot controlled
min_lc = 1  -- all lot controlled 
min_lc <> max_lc  -- mixed
```

Some people might prefer the more verbose versions:

```
min_lc = max_lc and max_lc = 0  -- no lot controlled
min_lc = max_lc and max_lc = 1  -- all lot controlled 
min_lc <> max_lc  -- mixed
```

Comment: Solution works for mixed lot, but the all or none solutions do not take into account the number of lines.  They return all line that are either lot controlled or not; even if there is only 1 line on the purchase order, or even if a purchase order has 1 line of each.  I am looking to see....IF a purchase order has more than 1 line...AND ALL of those lines are lot controlled.....IF a purchase order has more than 1 line...AND NONE of those lines are lot controlled.....IF a purchase order has more than 1 line...AND those lines are a A MIX of lot controlled and non-lot controlled.

Comment: @RyanCarhart . . . That is easily resolved.  I added a `having` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

I like using `NOT EXISTS` here:

```
SELECT POD.*
FROM table1 POD
JOIN (SELECT PONUMBER
      FROM table1 POD
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM table1 POD1
                        WHERE POD.PONUMBER = POD1.PONUMBER
                        AND POD1.LOTCONTROLLED = 1)
      GROUP BY PONUMBER
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) POD1 ON POD.PONUMBER = POD1.PONUMBER
```

This will omit the `PONUMBER` from results if any record from that `PONUMBER` has `LOTCONTROLLED` = 1 or 0, depending on what you put in the exists subquery.

To get only records that have a mix, you can use `COUNT().. HAVING`:

```
SELECT PONUMBER,
       ITEMNUMBER,
       LOTCONTROLLED
FROM table1 POD
JOIN (SELECT PONUMBER
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY PONUMBER
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LOTCONTROLLED) = 2
     ) POD1 ON POD.PONUMBER = POD1.PONUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I use the 1st query with lot controlled =1 it returns every item with a lotcontrol flag of 0 and includes purchase orders with only 1 line. When I change the LOTCONTROLLED to equal 0, it returns every item with a lot control flag of 1.  Appears to include purchase orders with only 1 line item though.   The second one appears to work as expected!!

Comment: @RyanCarhart My fault, I completely missed that condition.  Edited the top code block. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you also need to join the queries by Lot Controlled too, so I added it to the Group By and Inner Select so it could be joined:

### NO LOT CONTROLLED:

```
SELECT 
      `POD`.`PONUMBER`,
      `POD`.`ITEMNUMBER`,
      `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
    FROM
      table1 AS `POD`
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED', COUNT(`PONUMBER`)
        FROM table1
        WHERE `LOTCONTROLLED` = 0
        GROUP BY `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED'
        HAVING (COUNT(`PONUMBER`) > 1)
       ) as `POD1`
     ON `POD`.`PONUMBER` = `POD1`.`PONUMBER` AND `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED` = `POD1`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
```

### LOT CONTROLLED:

```
SELECT 
      `POD`.`PONUMBER`,
      `POD`.`ITEMNUMBER`,
      `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
    FROM
      table1 AS `POD`
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED', COUNT(`PONUMBER`)
        FROM table1
        WHERE `LOTCONTROLLED` = 1
        GROUP BY `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED'
        HAVING (COUNT(`PONUMBER`) > 1)
       ) as `POD1`
     ON `POD`.`PONUMBER` = `POD1`.`PONUMBER` AND `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED` = `POD1`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
```

### ALL LOT CONTROLLED:

```
SELECT 
      `POD`.`PONUMBER`,
      `POD`.`ITEMNUMBER`,
      `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
    FROM
      table1 AS `POD`
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED', COUNT(`PONUMBER`)
        FROM table1
        WHERE `LOTCONTROLLED` IN (0,1)
        GROUP BY `PONUMBER`, 'LOTCONTROLLED'
        HAVING (COUNT(`PONUMBER`) > 1)
       ) as `POD1`
     ON `POD`.`PONUMBER` = `POD1`.`PONUMBER` AND `POD`.`LOTCONTROLLED` = `POD1`.`LOTCONTROLLED`
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not return what I was looking for.  The second query you labeled LOT Controlled is what I assume was meant to be ALL LOT CONTROLLED, returned all LOT controlled lines even if there were also NON LOT controlled lines on the purchase order.  The last query which was meant to be a mix I assume, is leaving some lines out that should be included.  For example, it only returned the two  lot controlled lines from PO1.24, not the third line was NOT lot controlled.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. If that is the case, I think just adding

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    --No items in the group contain LotControlled 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   your_table 
    WHERE  ponumber IN (SELECT ponumber 
                        FROM   your_table 
                        GROUP  BY ponumber 
                        HAVING Sum(CONVERT(INT, lotcontrolled)) = 0) 

    --All Items Contain 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   your_table 
    WHERE  ponumber IN (SELECT ponumber 
                        FROM   your_table 
                        GROUP  BY ponumber 
                        HAVING Sum(CONVERT(INT, lotcontrolled)) = Count(*)) 

    --mixed 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   your_table 
    WHERE  ponumber IN (SELECT ponumber 
                        FROM   your_table 
                        GROUP  BY ponumber 
                        HAVING Sum(CONVERT(INT, lotcontrolled)) != Count(*) 
                               AND Sum(CONVERT(INT, lotcontrolled)) > 0)
```

Comment: This does not appear to take into account the need to return only line with more than 1 line item.  Also, I am using MySQL....not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: It does make a difference... my mistake